Altair chart mark_text background color/visual clarity
I've been playing with Altair charts in the context of Streamlit for making simple calculators. In one case I wanted to plot 3 bar charts next to each other to make an explainer for how progressive tax brackets work.
In one column is the total income, in the next is a bar drawn between the start of the bracket and the point at which the rate is paid for that bracket. Finally I stack all those intervals together to give the total tax owed.

I can't figure a good way to help the "Total Owed" number not have visual conflict with the grid lines. This is partly because I can't figure a good way to relate the chart's rendered size to the font size to do conditional checks for overlapping. I also believe there is no way to control the rendering of gridlines on a per-column basis.
Ideally I want to keep the gridlines thick and visible without disturbing the text. I could place the text for that column inside the stacked bars, but for certain configurations the multicolored bars make the text just as unreadable.
Here's a MRE:
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

# Example data
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'category': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    'value': [10, 20, 15, 25]
})

# Base chart with gridlines
chart = alt.Chart(data).mark_bar().encode(
    x='value:Q',
    y=alt.Y('category:N', axis=alt.Axis(grid=True, gridWidth=2, gridColor='darkslategray'))
)

text = alt.Chart(data).mark_text(
    align='left',
    baseline='middle',
    color='black'
).encode(
    x='value:Q',
    y='category:N',
    text=alt.Text('value:Q')
)

# Combine the charts
final_chart = chart + text

st.altair_chart(final_chart)

I tried using a mark_rect as a sort of backdrop for the text by adding this snippet to the above:
# Text with background
text_background = alt.Chart(data).mark_rect(
    color='black',
    opacity=0.7,
    height=20,
    width=20
).encode(
    x='value:Q',
    y='category:N'
)

and updating the composition of the final chart. However those rectangles are centered on the end of the bar and (again) with no way to relate the chart's size and the text font size I don't see a straightforward way to center it on the text (or even set an appropriate width to cover the whole text in response to its width).

Is there a convenient way to do this? Failing that, is there some other chart library I could use?

In addition to Joel's suggestion of using a background box, I have also had good results adding a copy of the text with a stroke behind the main text. This automatically adjusts the background to the right size.

import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

# Example data
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'category': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    'value': [10, 20, 15, 25]
})

# Base chart with gridlines
chart = alt.Chart(data).mark_bar().encode(
    x='value:Q',
    y=alt.Y('category:N', axis=alt.Axis(grid=True, gridWidth=2, gridColor='darkslategray'))
)

text = alt.Chart(data).mark_text(
    align='left',
    baseline='middle',
    color='black',
    dx=3  # Nudge the text to the right
).encode(
    x='value:Q',
    y='category:N',
    text=alt.Text('value:Q')
)

text_background = text.mark_text(
    align='left',
    baseline='middle',
    stroke='white',
    strokeWidth=5,
    strokeJoin='round',
    dx=3
)

# Combine the charts
final_chart = chart + text_background + text

final_chart


Nice! I like this one especially in crowded areas like my middle column where the text overlaps the mark_bar. With a rectangle removed for text background it makes the chart look odd, but this stroke approach is minimally disturbing to the data. Not having to calculate the size is also a huge plus for changing font sizes. I think this is better than the rectangle approach.

Great suggestion with the stroke! I agree this is more convenient than adding a background rectangle

I think your idea with a background rectangle would work. You can align it like you did with the text, and set the width to depend on the number of digits in the label:
# Example data
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'category': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
    'value': [5, 20, 150, 250, 3000]
})
# Base chart with gridlines
base = alt.Chart(data).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('value:Q').scale(domainMax=3500),
    y=alt.Y('category:N').axis(grid=True, gridWidth=2, gridColor='darkslategray')
)

text = base.mark_text(
    align='left',
    dx=2,
    color='black'
).encode(
    text=alt.Text('value:Q')
)

text_bg = base.mark_rect(
    color='white',
    height=20,
    # width=alt.expr('10 + 5 * length(toString(datum.value))'),  # Equivalent
    width=alt.expr(10 + 5 * alt.expr.length(alt.expr.toString((alt.datum.value)))),
    align='left'
)

base + text_bg + text


If you want to experiment with having the text overlaid on bars with different color instead, you could set the text color conditionally on the luminance of the bar bg color as per https://github.com/vega/altair/pull/3614

That conditional text color technique is excellent and I'll definitely keep it in mind. Aligning the rectangle definitely helps. The only problem with the rectangle approach is what happens when the number is a small number of digits as opposed to a larger one (i.e. $10 vs. $250,000.00). Do you know of a technique to measure the rendered length of mark_text? Or even the width of an entire column? I know this could be tricky because I'm also using streamlit instead of pure vega-altair.

@FawltyPlay I see, for that you could set the width to an expression that checks the number of digits in the label, something like length(toString(datum.value)). I updated my answer with an example. You could use a fancier formula that accounts for not all character being the same exact width (or use a monospace font), but this simpler approach still seems to get the job done.

That does get the job done! Thank you for the insight and example!

One follow-up question, in my actual application I use a format string in my text object like so: text=alt.Text("bracket_rate:Q", format='.0%'). The datum.bracket_rate way of accessing the data would use what's in the dataFrame (0.37) while the formatted value is instead 37%. Is there a way to use the formatted version as an argument to length()? If not I can simply calculate the lengths in python.

Ah, these are vega-lite functions so I can use length(toString(format(datum.bracket_rate, ".0%"))) to get what I wanted.

@FawltyPlay Yes, sorry I should have mentioned that. Actually, altair 5.5 was just released yesterday which has better support for using the alt.expr module to write these vega lite expression strings (e.g. docstrings) via alt.expr.length etc. I updated the answer to include this approach as well
